# Dynamically add functions in class

Tags: python, function, dynamic

I'm dynamically adding functions in class (`A`) with some variables (`my_name`). But when I call functions in class (`A`) I get correct function (correct name of function) but with variables from last function. How to dynamically set variables in function or how to solve problem like this?

```
class A:
    pass


function_name_list = ['first/function', 'second/function', 'third/function']


def add_method(cls, fnctname):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        setattr(cls, fnctname, wrapper)
        return func

    return decorator


def create_functions():
    for x in function_name_list:
        name = x.replace('/', '')

        @add_method(A, name)
        def foo(value):
            my_name = copy.deepcopy(name)
            with open('./file' + str(my_name) + '.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(time.time()) + ',' + my_name + ',' + str(value) + "\n")
                print('Call: ', my_name)


a = A()
create_functions()

for x in function_name_list:
    name = x.replace('/', '')
    getattr(a, '%s' % name)(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `create_function`, `def foo()` binds to the variable `name`. It will pick up the **current** value of `name` when the function is called. There is only one `name` variable so all of your `foo` functions are bound to the same variable.

If you really want to do this you must ensure there is a separate variable bound to each function. Pull the entire body of your `for` loop out to a separate function then it will create different variables for each function.

```
def create_functions():
    for x in function_name_list:
        create_foo(x.replace('/', ''))

def create_foo(name):
        @add_method(A, name)
        def foo(value):
            with open('./file' + str(name) + '.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(time.time()) + ',' + name + ',' + str(value) + "\n")
                print('Call: ', name)
```

(`copy.deepcopy()` on a `str` will return the original `str` so I removed it.)

A much simpler technique is just to bind arguments using `functools.partial`:

```
import functools

def foo(self, value, name):
    with open('./file' + str(name) + '.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(time.time()) + ',' + name + ',' + str(value) + "\n")
        print('Call: ', name)

def create_functions():
    for x in function_name_list:
        name = x.replace('/', ''))
        setattr(A, name, functools.partial(foo, name=name))
```